# How I can register the access to my Web Service (PHP)?

Tags: php, web-services

I have been researching on how I can keep track (tracking in spanish) how many requests are made to any of the web pages offering a service coded in PHP. These pages do not have HTML code, so I cannot use Google Analytics for this purpose. Is there any way to do this?

The only thing that I can think of is to use PHP variables such as = `$ _SERVER ['PHP_SELF'], $ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'], $ _SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ _SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, etc., and implement my own tracking.

Thank you very much.

Comment: HTML in a web service with Json? I dont know if it would be a good idea!

Comment: there's always the web-server access logs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a simple script that logs $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and whatever other information you'd like to have about the request -- to a MySQL db -- or even to an SQLite -- is your best option.

You could even log them to a file:

```
file_put_contents("/path-to/non/web/accessible/file.we", "Script: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']} Visited by: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} at {$time}\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

But that's generally not a good idea for production -

You may also want to check this out:
https://www.php.net/get_browser

for even more information.

Comment: The main idea is not affecting the performance of web service, but I think we should sacrifice a little if I want to run that tracking. In any case, this web service is just under development. If I find an optimal solution, will post it here. Thank you all.

Comment: Well, that line will handle tracking just fine - It isn't a good idea for production because that file can get out of hand quickly -- and you won't have any sorting functions outside of what you get in a text editor.